# Convert any document into grayscale PDF using PDF Export?

Tags: pdf, export, grayscale, oracle-outside-in

I have converted/exported color document into color PDF using Oracle Outside In **PDF Export**.

Is it possible to convert/export this color document into **grayscale**/blacknwhite **PDF** using Oracle Outside In **PDF Export**?

Answer (score 0):

SCCGRAPHIC_SMOOTHGRAYSCALESIZING is defined as "resize using antialiasing for grayscale graphics only (no antialiasing for color graphics)". This has no effect on creating output in black and white; it is used to determine if grayscale graphics from the input file should be antialiased.

You cannot do this with PDF Export and would be encouraged to try Image Export with TIFF output, which can be made to produce black and white with SCCOPT_IMAGEX_TIFFOPTIONS->SCCGRAPHIC_TIFF1BITBW. TIFF is often a suitable replacement for PDF for archiving purposes, if that is your goal.